# How to use Stripe payouts with customer invoices

Tags: c#, stripe-payments

I have a question about how to implement proper payouts for my system/platform.

Let me explain a little further. I have a platform like Lyft, but instead of creating and issuing charges right after each ride. I'm creating invoice items, so that the rider is only charged once every invoice billing cycle(ex. every 2 weeks). Now, I understand there is no destination id for an invoice or invoice item using Stripe. So I need to tell Stripe somehow what funds need to go to the driver. How do I do that? It seems like the method would be to create a [Stripe payout](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_payout) with the destination as the drivers bank account id. But after attempting this with both the drivers external acount id and the bank account id, Stripe threw an exception saying 'No such external account exists acct_123456ABCD'

Would the method I described above be the correct way to implement this? Or is there a better way or more prescribed way?

FYI - To understand why I'm creating invoice items, instead of instant charges immediately after a ride, it's because the charges for my service are all very small ($1.00-$3.00), so to avoid a Stripe flat fee of $.30/charge I'm aggregating them into an invoice, where there will be only one flat fee per billing cycle.

Thanks for any help.

For ex purposes I'll include an example of what I'm doing below.
First I create an invoice item, then I create a payout.

```
            var invoiceItemOptions = new StripeInvoiceItemCreateOptions()
            {
                Amount = tipPricing.GetTotalAmountCharged(),
                Currency = "USD", //defaultCard.CurrencyCode,
                CustomerId = '12334567',

                Metadata = new Dictionary<String, String>() { { "EventId", 123 } }
            };

            var invoiceItemService = new StripeInvoiceItemService();
            StripeInvoiceLineItem invoiceItem = invoiceItemService.Create(invoiceItemOptions);
            StripeResponse invoiceResponse = invoiceItem.StripeResponse;

            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            var payoutOptions = new StripePayoutCreateOptions()
            {
                Amount = tipPricing.GetTotalDestinationAmount(hasBeenChargedThisMonth), 
                Currency = "USD",
                Destination = bankAccount.ExternalAccountId, //bankAccount.AccountId,
                Metadata = new Dictionary<String, String>() { { "EventId", 123 } }
            };
            var payoutService = new StripePayoutService();
            StripePayout payoutCharge = payoutService.Create(payoutOptions);
            StripeResponse payoutResponse = payoutCharge.StripeResponse;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Payouts are intended to happen on the Connected Account's Balance -> Bank Account, rather than from your Platform to the Connected Account's Bank Account.

You've got at least two choices for funds flows here:

1. You could run the Invoices (or even a $0 subscription with a two week billing cycle) on your Platform. You could listen for webhooks when `invoice.payment_succeeded`, then move the funds to the destination connected account using a `Transfer`, see https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges-transfers. From the Connected Account's balance it will pay out to their bank account, or you can initiate a Payout (if on manual payouts, https://stripe.com/docs/connect/payouts#using-manual-payouts)
2. You could create an Invoice Items / Invoices or a Subscription directly on the Connected Account. This gets slightly tricker as you will need to remit the fee for your platform, but you can do that with Application Fees, see https://stripe.com/docs/connect/subscriptions#working-with-invoices

Comment: Hi duck. I'm using the 1st option with a $0 sub., billing every 2 weeks. Then when I receive the webhook, I can transfer funds to the Connected Account, but I'm reading the doc. and concerned about the limitations with transfers. Specifically needing to have the platform (my Stripe account?) and the connected account being in the same region! Does this mean that if my account is in the US I can't transfer funds to a connected account in Australia? Maybe I don't understand the transfer limitations!?

Comment: I would talk to Stripe directly about this and describe your use case in detail. It's not so much a technical limitation as it is a compliance one I believe.

Comment: Hi duck. I sent an email to them. But I would like to ask you how you would implement this type of a system. Think of Lyft/Uber, but no charge for the ride. Only tips after the ride! So with tips being low ($1-$3) I thought an invoice would be best to avoid the flat fee per charge. But my question comes when a rider takes a ride in another country. Now I have to transfer money from my platform (US) to a connected account in another country!

Comment: Hi duck. my two options so far - 1. charge immediately, but make the lowest tip amount $3.00 or $4.00 so the .30 cent flat charge fee doesn't take so much out of the overall tip. But I would like to be able to tip $1+, so that 30% isn't taken from each tip, which means I need another solution like an invoice that adds up all tips and charges once at the end of the billing cycle. This solution is just really confusing as to how I would implement it!

Comment: That makes sense as far as not wanting to create separate charges for $1-4 charges. I'd wait to hear back from Stripe on the cross country side of this --- that does complicate things a little bit! Alternatively you could try to write some logic on your side to aggregate charges for a user's account on a per-country basis (e.g. they are in the US, but visit Canada, for that month they'd see two charges at the end of month/two weeks --- one for US rides, another for Canadian rides), thus you would not have to worry about cross border transfers.